# If $f(r)=r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$, simplify $f(r+1)-f(r)$ and use your result to find

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

If $f(r)=r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$, simplify $f(r+1)-f(r)$ and use your result to find $$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3$$

I need help with the second part of the question because the book does not give any answers for the second part.

I have found that

$f(r+1)-f(r)$

$=(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)-r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$

$=(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4-r)$

$=4(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$

I am certain that $f(r)=r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3) =4(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ because that is the answer given by the book.

To find $$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3$$
I solved  for $$\sum_{r=1}^n [4(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)]$$

$$=\sum_{r=1}^n [(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)-r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)]$$
$=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{r=1}^n [4r^3+24r^2+44r+24]=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^n 4r^3+ \sum_{r=1}^n24r^2 + \sum_{r=1}^n44r + \sum_{r=1}^n 24=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24$$

$$\begin{align} 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24-24[\frac{n}{2}(n+1)]^2 -44[\frac{n}{2}(n+1)]-24n\\ 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24-24[\frac{n^2}{4}(n+1)^2]-44[\frac{n}{2}(n+1)]-24n\\ 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24-6n^2(n+1)^2-22n(n+1)-24n\\ 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=(n^3+6n^2+11n+6)(n+4)-24-6n^2(n^2+2n+1)-22n(n+1)-24n\\ 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=n^4+10n^3+35n^2+50n+24-24-6n^4-12n^3-6n^2-22n^2-22n-24n\\ 4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3&=-5n^4-2n^3+7n^2+4n \end {align}$$

I know that summation of a finite series should be positive, but the book does not give a solution for $$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3$$

So what went wrong?

Comment: you used the formula for sum of cubes for sum of squares

Comment: Your first calculation doesn't make sense to me. $f(r)=r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ indeed, but this is not equal to $(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)-r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$, which is $f(r+1)-f(r)$, so I think you made some typos there?

Comment: @Thorgott I’ve edited my working, thanks for spotting the mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [J. W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557337/if-fr-rr1r2r3-simplify-fr1-fr-and-use-your-result-to-find/3557348#comment7314984_3557337) indicated, you made a mistake in the third line of your set of equations, i.e., in the third term on the right side of

$$4 \sum_{r=1}^nr^3=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-24-24[\frac{n^2}{4}(n+1)^2]-44[\frac{n}{2}(n+1)]-24n \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You are using that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2 = \frac{n^2}{4}(n+1)^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This is actually the sum for the cubes, which you are trying to find, as you can see in [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). Instead, the sum for the squares, as shown in that same Wikipedia article, is

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Your explanation is helpful. Now I’ve got $\frac{1}{4}(n^4+2n^3+n^2)$ for the answer, which seems more possible